# Filter dataframe using multiple values

Tags: dataframe, filter, julia

As the title says, I have a dataframe and I want to filter (keep) rows where the `id` variable is either `1` or `2`.

An example:

```
using DataFrames

# eaxample data set
df1 = DataFrame(id = repeat(1:3, 3),
name = repeat(["bob", "jane", "steve"], inner = 3))


# filtering based on a single id - works fine 
kp_id = 1
df1[df1.id .== 1, :]

# filter on multipel id's - my attempt returns an empty dataframe
kp_id = (1,2)
df1[df1.id .== in(df1.id, kp_id), :]
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `df1[in.(df1.id, Ref(kp_id)), :]` or with unicode operator: `df1[df1.id .∈ Ref(kp_id), :]`. Note that `Ref(x)` avoids broadcasting over `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to writing a boolean expression that generates the desired BitVector. While you work on this, skip the indexing first and just work on

```
df1.id .== 1
```

Then a useful tool in julia is to consider the single case first:

```
julia> in(1, (1,2))
true
julia> in(3, (1,2))
false
```

so far so good! Lets broadcast this, but only on the first argument, so we protect the second argument with a Ref

```
julia> in.(df1.id, Ref((1,2)))
9-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 0
```

thus

```
df1[in.(df1.id, Ref(kp_id)), :]
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

You might prefer the `filter` function as more readable:

```
julia> filter(:id => in((1, 2)), df1)
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id     name
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  bob
   2 │     2  bob
   3 │     1  jane
   4 │     2  jane
   5 │     1  steve
   6 │     2  steve
```

If you want to use indexing you can write:

```
julia> df1[in((1, 2)).(df1.id), :]
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id     name
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  bob
   2 │     2  bob
   3 │     1  jane
   4 │     2  jane
   5 │     1  steve
   6 │     2  steve
```

Both syntaxes take advantage of the fact that `in((1, 2))` creates a new function that checks if its argument is in `(1, 2)`.